# Add a photo to emoji android keyboard

Tags: java, android, emoji

I need to put my own emoji into keyboard in Andorid. I can create an custom emoji keyboard with Android Studio but I don't know how to put a photo which is not in the official emoji list.

Comment: Please tell exactly what are you trying to accomplish. Are you trying to add your own emoji?

Comment: Yes it is exactly what I need.

Comment: pl read this things https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27186651/creating-softkeyboard-with-custom-emoji

Comment: Are you trying to add these emoji's within your application level or at the whole Android level. Example When you use your emoji keyboard display in Gmail, messages, Chat messenger etc or just within your standalone application example skype

Comment: Idea is to put my own emoji in keyboard. If I try to put it on a costum keyboard (keyboard apps in playstore) I think that would be imposible to edit apk, but I can create my keyboard wich  contains my own emoji. Concretely I need this for one time use in instagram.The problem is how can I put my photo (emoji) into keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

Try [Emoticon Keyboard](https://github.com/chiragjain/Emoticons-Keyboard). This type of keyboard would work within the app and not  with other apps on board. This keyboard is not using Unicode sequences but rather just local image assets.
Hope this helps.